# In plotly, how to pass a list or a dict of trace names to the graph_objects.Layout functions?

Tags: python, plotly

I've made a simple function that takes a dict of labels and corresponding dataframes (with same columns), a column to trace from every dataframe and a barmode setting. Here is the code:

```
def multiple_histogram_plotter(dict_of_labels_and_dataframes, column, barmode):
    data_for_fig = []
    for name_of_df, df_chosen in dict_of_labels_and_dataframes.items():
        hist = go.Histogram(x=df_chosen[column], opacity=0.75, histnorm='probability')
        data_for_fig.append(hist)
    fig = go.Figure(data=data_for_fig, layout=go.Layout(barmode=barmode))
    fig.show()
```

What this does is draws any number of histograms I want in the same space, depending on the length of the dict passed. In its current form, though, it names all the histograms as 'trace0, trace1', etc. I was trying to find a parameter in the Layout function that would rename the traces, but haven't been able to, Google didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` of a trace isn't attached to the layout of the figure, but rather `name` for each trace in `fig.data`, subsettable through `fig.data[0]` (for the first trace). Below is an example. If you take the time to share a fully reproducible example of what you're working for, we can talk about the details.

```
(Histogram({
     'alignmentgroup': 'True',
     'bingroup': 'x',
     'hovertemplate': 'total_bill=%{x}<br>count=%{y}<extra></extra>',
     'legendgroup': '',
     'marker': {'color': '#636efa', 'pattern': {'shape': ''}},
     'name': '',   # <===================================================
     'offsetgroup': '',
     'orientation': 'v',
     'showlegend': False,
     'x': array([16.99, 10.34, 21.01, ..., 22.67, 17.82, 18.78]),
     'xaxis': 'x',
     'yaxis': 'y'
 }),)
```